# Cannot edit start menu links

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

Any changes to this folder

> c:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick
>   Launch\User Pinned\StartMenu\

have no effect in the start menu

Shortcuts that I copy there manually are not visible

wtf.......

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
```

or

```
%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
```